# Return collection of files to new page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to build websites that will show all file from root directory so opened ASP.NET  Web Application project.

inside this folder i have several folder and click on each folder name (i have buttons for each folder) will lead me to new page with all the file within this folder.
So i added new controller called folder1:

```
public class WebMailController : Controller
{
    private List<string> list = new List<string>();

    //
    // GET: /folder1/

    public FileInfo Index()
    {
        FileInfo[] array = GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo file in array)
            return file;
        return null;
    }

    private FileInfo[] GetFiles()
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\folder");
        FileInfo[] fileInfo = di.GetFiles("*.doc");
        return fileInfo;
    }
```

}

My problems:

1. currently i can see only the first file from the folder
2. hoe can i open new page but still see the main page template ?

Answer (score 0):

You see first file because you are returning only first:

```
FileInfo[] array = GetFiles();
foreach (FileInfo file in array) return file;
```

So you get first item and immediately return it to `View`. Instead you should return list of files.

Talking about **second** item - use `PartialView`.
In such case Controller should return `PartialView` instead of list of items:

```
public ActionResult Files()
{
    return PartialView("_Files", GetFiles());
}
```

And View should look something like:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("LoadFiles", "Files", "Home", new AjaxOptions { 
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
    UpdateTargetId = "files-div"
})

<div id="files-div">
    @Html.Partial("_Files")
</div>
```

Nice [example of `PartialView`](http://mvc4beginner.com/Tutorial/MVC-Partial-Views.html)

Comment: Can i have an example ?

Comment: It is part of your Home/whatever `View`. You should also define `PArtialView` "_Files".

Comment: I put it in Index.cshtml under @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";  
}
and get an error: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The partial view '_Files' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:

~/Views/Home/_Files.aspx

~/Views/Home/_Files.ascx

~/Views/Shared/_Files.aspx

~/Views/Shared/_Files.ascx

~/Views/Home/_Files.cshtml

~/Views/Home/_Files.vbhtml

~/Views/Shared/_Files.cshtml

~/Views/Shared/_Files.vbhtml

Comment: Have you added `PartialView` "_Files"? http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/617361/Partial-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC-4

Comment: i don't have this windows after add controller: Add Scaffold dialog box and click MVC 5  Controller - Empty

Answer (score 0):

As for only seeing the first folder - your return type is `FileInfo` and you return the first iteration of your `foreach` loop.  You want to return an `IEnumerable<FileInfo>` and use `yield return file;` in your `foreach` loop (and toss the `return null`) - but why even bother when you can just return the results of `GetFiles()`?

```
public IEnumerable<FileInfo> Index()
{
    FileInfo[] array = GetFiles();
    foreach (FileInfo file in array)
        yield return file;
}
```

My best guess at what you're looking for with your second question is that you want to pass the return `FileInfo` results to another page.  You could save the results in session or `TempData` and call `RedirectToAction` to redirect the user to another action that will consume the `FileInfo` results:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    TempData[ "files" ] = GetFiles();

    RedirectToAction( "Files" );
}

public ActionResult Files()
{
    var fileInfos = TempData[ "files" ];

    // do stuff with fileInfos
}
```